# Set phps $_REQUEST['variable_name'] in JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript

is it possible to store a variable through javascript so that I can read it in php using $_REQUEST['variable_name'].

for eg. 
let's say i have

```
$adcategory=$_REQUEST['category_id'];
```

somewhere in the php page, and I would like to pre set that "variable" somewhere before that in javascript, so that it could be read through php.

Does this make any sense? Is this possible?

Thank you for your time!
Andrej

Comment: Are you trying to 

1. Start loading webpage, set variable in JS, check variable in PHP, finish loading webpage

OR

2. Load a variable in javascript, browse to new webpage, read JS variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's less of a technical problem, more of how you structure your code and interaction between the PHP backend and in-page Javascript.

To get the $category_id variable into Javascript, the typical approach is:

```
<?php print "<script>category_id = $category_id;</script>";
```

To have your Javascript code send a catid back to a PHP page:

```
$("#id").load("page.php?category_id="+category_id);
```

This would ping it back to PHPs $_REQEUST[] array. But the question is why you need the variable available in Javascript *first*.

Answer (score 1):

> Does this make any sense? Is this possible?

No and no :)

PHP executes on server side before anything else, Javascript in the browser. The only way to do this in JavaScript would be to manipulate the form that *makes* that request before it gets submitted.

Comment: I think your second part is what he was asking about

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Apache:

Try setting the default in a file (called "my_vars.php" in this example), then in your .htaccess file:

`php_value auto_prepend_file /absolute/path/to/my_vars.php`

For the js side, take the value of what you set in that file at page load.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var = <?=$what_i_set_in_my_vars?>;
</script>
```

Research:
http://www.google.com/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=php_value+auto_prepend_file

I have found that auto prepend is good if you want to use a sort of settings file for storing stuff like this, IMHO. That way you don't need to jump through hoops, the draw back is that it will be included on each page.

Comment: If this is what I'm thinking it is, it's modifying the header and from what I recall not all browsers support this.

Comment: It simply instructs php to prepend the contents of the file to any .php page. Happens on the server side. It is actually supposed to be in the php.ini file. adding it to the .htaccess file is a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

> Does this make any sense? Is this possible?

Yes, you need to bind it to the request string.

If you're calling `foobar.php`, change the onsubmit behavior of the form and make it:

```
'foobar.php?category_id=' + your_javascript_category_id_value
```